# Starting selenium webdriver with php

Tags: php, selenium

I have problem when starting selenium webdriver
when I start with

```
chromedriver --port=4444
```

run php file and got error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: JSON decoding of remote response failed.
Error code: 4
```

https://prnt.sc/wcmlga

tried other command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

got same error

here is my php code

```
  $host = 'http://localhost:4444';
  $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
  $options = new ChromeOptions();
  // $options->addArguments(['--headless', 'window-size=1024,768']);
  $options->addArguments(['--disable-extensions',]);
  $options->setExperimentalOption('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging','enable-automation']);
  $options->setExperimentalOption('useAutomationExtension', false);
  $options->setExperimentalOption('w3c', false);
  $options->setExperimentalOption('prefs', array(
     "download.prompt_for_download" => false,
     "download.default_directory" => "/tmp",
     "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" => 2,
     "profile.password_manager_enabled" => false,
     "credentials_enable_service" => false
  ));
  $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
  $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
```

selenium is running screenshoot
https://prnt.sc/wcmjw1

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, error logs should be provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

after several experience, i found my error, all command is not wrong.

im use `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`

i forgot to update chromedriver.exe

after update chromedriver.exe , my problem has been solved